# In Android - Webview Screen sharing, what permission required?

Tags: android, webview, webrtc

I am using **Android web-view** to run a website in app, while running, I am getting this error
[Image (Here).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPqGu.jpg)
how to **share my screen** using android app.

```
mWebRTCWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebRTCWebView.loadUrl("https://sunshine-mytutor.com/student_app/");
```

May i know what permission i need to give to share my screen...??

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

> I am using WebRTC in my website for screen sharing like zoom screen share in website